# Rewrite dictionary attributes in "settings.py"

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

Is there a pythonic way to rewrite dictionary values in files like `settings.py`?

Sometimes, it is useful to make a `*.py` file with some settings. In my `settings.py` there is a common `dictionary` with `keys` and their `values`. For example where the download stopped. In this case, I want to rewrite this `dictionary` to be able to continue from this step.

**settings.py:**

```
settings = {'driver':'firefox',
           'last_processed_file':'x1.txt'}
```

What if I want to rewrite the 'x1.txt' to another file/string? Of course I can do that using some uncomfortable parsing or saving the dictionary as an object but both has disadvantages.

So if I want to change the value of 'last_processed_file' I would do something like settings.change_value('last_processed_file','x2.txt') and the result would be rewritten file `settings.py`:

**settings.py:**

```
settings = {'driver':'firefox',
           'last_processed_file':'x2.txt'}
```

Comment: you can pickle dump the dictionary into a file and load from a file

Comment: Yes but in that case, me and nobody would be able to change values (like in django settings.py).

Comment: you can always load and change the value dump again

Comment: Why don't you take out the dictionary declaration part from this file to some other file (say data.json)? Then this settings map should just be reading this file instead of declaring a map.

settings = read_data("data.json")

data.json will be 

{'driver':'firefox',
           'last_processed_file':'x2.txt'}

then when you wish to change the file, all you need to do is read the file to an in memory object and change the values and writing it back without changing your python file.

Comment: ** read the file to an in memory object and change the values and writing it back without changing your python file.

And if u wish to update during execution then you can register signal handlers to the code (say sighup to reload)

Answer (score 0):

May be silly but couldn't you just dump the string representation of your dictionary back to your `settings.py` (if you only have "simple" values of cause):

```
settings = {'driver':'firefox',
           'last_processed_file':'x1.txt'}
def dump(fpath, **kwargs):
    with open(fpath, 'w') as outfile:
        for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
            outfile.write('{0} = {1}\n'.format(key, repr(value)))
dump('/tmp/settings.cfg', settings=settings)
```